# Как присвоить unsigned char const * к void*?

Tags: c++

У меня не много опыта с С++, но вот, что мне нужно сделать. У меня есть метод который должен скастить unsigned char const * к void*.

```
void foo()
{
...
    void * sound_data = nullptr;
    get_pointer_on_sound_data(sound_data);
...
}

void get_pointer_on_sound_data(void * sound_data)
{
...
    unsigned char const *   m_pData = m_sound_destination_data.m_pData;
    sound_data = reinterpret_cast<void*>(const_cast<unsigned char*>(m_pData));
...
}
```

Но я получаю вот такую ошибку

> error C2100: illegal indirection

Как сделать, чтоб это работало?

**EDIT**

Если говорить конкретно, то мне это нужно для использования в юнити на стороне C#. Я хочу так сделать, чтоб вытянуть поинтер из нативного кода на С# на для дальнейшего испльзования. Вот так выглядит апи с нативной стороны

```
DllExport bool stream_init_model_audio(void * native_stream_ptr, void* sound_data, long * sound_data_size);
```

И вот так я обращаюсь к нему на стороне C#

```
[DllImport(m_pluginName)]
    public static extern bool stream_init_model_audio(IntPtr native_stream_ptr, ref IntPtr sound_data, ref long sound_data_size);
```

***EDIT2***

Сейчас действительно не получается воспроизвести ошибку, но проблема теперь в том, что не получается получить поинтер на стороне c#, хотя вроде в дебаге видно, что присваевается.

Comment: Удаление константности очень редко бывает оправдано. К тому же вы уверены, что проблема именно в касте?

Comment: Заявленная ошибка в приведенном коде не возникает. Как не видно в нем и необходимости делать какие-то касты. Зато есть бессмысленная передача параметра sound_data, который сразу же перетирается новым значением.

Comment: Пишите проще  --  `sound_data = (void *)m_pData;`

Comment: @avp Ага, а лучший способ убить осу - это загнать ее под шкаф и отпилить ножки.

Comment: Если указатель надо вытянуть, зачем вы его передаете как входящий параметр? По идее тут надо возвращать структуру с результатом и указателями.

Comment: Вы уверены что в функции `stream_init_model_audio` указатели это возвращаемые значения? Сам указатель передается по значению а не по ссылке, и выполняя `sound_data = smth` результата вы не добъетесь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Сейчас действительно не получается воспроизвести ошибку, но проблема
> теперь в том, что не получается получить поинтер на стороне c#, хотя
> вроде в дебаге видно, что присваевается.

Вы путаете указатель на указатель и указатель, `void **` and `void *`, при передаче второго в функцию, его значение будет скопировано, а при передаче первого, будет передано значение где лежит сам указатель:

```
int copy(void *p_data) {
    p_data = (void *)(0xffffffff); // для теста
}

int ref(void **pp_data) {
    (*pp_data) = (void *)(0xffffffff); // для теста
}

int main() {
    void *p_data = nullptr;

    copy(p_data);
    printf("copy value is: %p\n", p_data);

    ref(&p_data);
    printf("ref value is: %p\n", p_data);
}
```

Тоже самое происходит при передачи `ref IntPtr` из [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

[C](https://ideone.com/0DTcjC)

[C#](https://ideone.com/5G8XNS)

```
copy value is: (nil)
ref value is: 0xffffffff
```

P.S. Ну и немного отсебятины про то:

> Как присвоить unsigned char const * к void*?

Да все просто, но немного не так, а последуем тому же примеру выше:

```
void test(void **const pp_data) { // or void const **pp_data
    // позволяем изменить значение на которое указывает указатель, не позволяя менять данные.
    (*pp_data) = (void *const)(0xffffffff); // Снова же добавлю: для теста
}
```

Comment: Да, действительно это была проблема, спасибо. Насчет последнего примера я попробовал и получил вот такую ошибку `error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const void *' to 'void *const '`

Comment: Ой, это я намудрил, там перед `pp_data` нужен `const`.